# Mysql configured correctly for remote connection but php code failing connection?

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, mysqli, remote-access

I went through the grueling process of figuring out how to bind the correct address in the config file and connect mysql to my remote server.  Yesterday it was working with different code and now it's not connecting.  I'm getting the die "connection failed: " but its not showing me the connect_error as I called for so cant even figure out the issue?   Does anyone see something wrong with my code? NOTE:  I know this is unsafe and I usually do prepared statements but just trying to work with connection to the db issue now.

```
<?php
$server = "174.---.--.187";
$username = "dylanto";
$pass = "------";
$db = "survey";
//$port = 3306;
//create connection
$conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $pass, $db);
//check connection
if (!$conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);}

$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST ['pass'];

$sql = "insert into login (user, pass) values ('$user','$pass')";

if ($conn->query($sql)==TRUE) {
echo "Account created";}

else {echo "something went wrong";}
$con->close;
?>
```

Html code:

```
<html><head><title>Log-in</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sytle.css"></head>
<body>
<center><u><strong><h2>Login</h2></u></strong></center>
<br />
<center>
<form action="signup_process.php" method="POST">
Pick Username: <br>
<input type ="text" name = "user"><br>
Pick Password:<br>
<input type ="password" name ="pass"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign-up">
</form></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if (!$conn->connect_error) {` this = there is no connection error remove the `!`

Comment: in addition your code is open to SQL injection attacks you need to learn PDO or mysqli prepared staments

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: Thanks guys I'll try this now.  If you read my question the note at the end says "NOTE: I know this is unsafe and I usually use prepared statements but just testing this for mysql connection right now"   But thank you!

Comment: @cmorrissey  that simple fix did the trick thank you!!

Comment: @do734 are you going live with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From

```
if (!$conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

To:

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Since if ($conn->connect_error) = If any error and if (!$conn->connect_error) if no error.

For prepared statement :

From:

```
$sql = "insert into login (user, pass) values ('$user','$pass')";

if ($conn->query($sql)==TRUE) {
echo "Account created";}

else {echo "something went wrong";}
```

To :

```
//sanityze POST
$user = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, htmlspecialchars($_POST['user'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));
$pass = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, htmlspecialchars($_POST['pass'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));

//use prepared

$stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into login (user, pass) values (?,?)");

//bind parameter
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $pass)

 $stmt->execute();

//then check
```

Comment: Yea the guy in the comments already told me this but thanks,  it makes logical sense now I just missed that.

Comment: If you're going to include a prepared statement, there's no use for both `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: Yea I like to use prepared statements